# How to use image as a map with zoom level in android

Tags: android, dictionary, zooming

I am trying to implement an app where a simple image (floor plan of a room ) is used as a map.

Actually I am not clearly sure about how to do it. But after some searching, I follow one of instructions in a blog.

I am using a WebView to show the image. I am using three different size of the image for three specific zoom level.

There are two button zoomIn and zoomOut. I am just loading a different image when zoom level is changed.

Is it right way?

Comment: Yes, you use an url for both zoomIn and zoomOut

Answer (score 0):

To enable zoom on the WebView, add the following code:

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

for your button 1:

```
int zoom_level=100;
webview1.setInitialScale(zoom_level);
webview1.loadData("url");
```

repeat same for other buttons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I am trying to use this api: (https://github.com/moagrius/MapView) to implement an image as a map. I think it is very good api for doing this work.